# Django rest framework serializer ignores extra_kwargs or custom attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to make an api which is slightly different for the client and the main user. So I want to add the client later if the role is client.

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ["id", "name", "location", "location_lat", "location_lng", "client"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.role == Roles.CLIENT.name:
            validated_data["client"] = user.client
```

The dumbed down model lookst like this

```
class Store(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I now call the serializer with the user that has the role client I get this response:

```
{"client":["This field is required."]}
```

Which is correct. But the weird thing happens when I add `extra_kwargs` to the StoreSerializer. If I change the serializer to:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ["id", "name", "location", "location_lat", "location_lng", "client"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "client": { "required": False }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.role == Roles.CLIENT.name:
            validated_data["client"] = user.client
```

Or change it to

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ["id", "name", "location", "location_lat", "location_lng", "client"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.role == Roles.CLIENT.name:
            validated_data["client"] = user.client
```

I get the same response. How can this be? Client should not be required right?

Versions:

- Django: 2.2.3
- Django rest framework: 3.9.4

Comment: Have you tried setting the client foreign key to allow null and blank?

Comment: Yes I did but only in the serializer. I did not try that in the model. But obviously I don't want that

Comment: When you make those requests is the client being set to anything and/or is the user.role equal to Roles.CLIENT?

Comment: In my situation either the user is a client which means the user model has a client attribute. If the user does not have the role client it means he has send the client with the request. If that makes sense?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which DRF version is this? Also please add the whole `StoreSerializer` definition in the latter two cases and an example of `data` you're passing.

Comment: I think you need to use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead of `UUIDField`. 


`class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.Clients.objects.all(), allow_null=True)`

Comment: @Vibhu I tried that but I get the same response that client is required

Answer (score 0):

Store model should be like this: (note `blank`)

```
class Store(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Now on DB level you are allowing client to be null in Store model.

Serializer this way:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.Client.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ["id", "name", "client"]
    ...
```

Your serializer should work now.

Answer (score -3):

If what you said is correct then I'd pop off that field. Probably best anyway so that the API explorer doesn't include it when the user isn't authorized.

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ["id", "name", "location", "location_lat", "location_lng", "client"]

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context["request"].user.role == Roles.CLIENT.name:
            del self.fields["client"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.role == Roles.CLIENT.name:
            validated_data["client"] = user.client
```

Comment: When the field is initialized with `required=False` or mentioned as such in `extra_kwargs`, the field should not raise such complaint. Removing the field altogether does not serve the root cause in any way.

Comment: Agreed on that it shouldn't work that way, but absolutely diasgree that it doesn't solve their issue. If a user who can't populate client browses out to the browse-able API, they shouldn't even see the option to select a client. The only way to achieve that is to remove the field.